# Finding the effective maximum number of subspaces in a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, galois-theory, gaussian, vector-spaces

Hi mathoverflow community, may be some one may give me a hint on the following problem before I spend much time on brute force search.

For $q$ a prime number and $n=6$, let $\mathbb {F}_{q}^{n}$ be an $n-$dimensional vector space over $GF_{q}$.
Furthermore let $ U_i, U_j$ and $U_k$ be disjoint subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^n$ having each dimension $2$, with $i, j, k \in \{1,\dots, n\}$, $i\neq j \neq k$.
What is the *effective* maximum number of disjoint  subspaces of dimension $2$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$ so that $\langle U_i, U_j \rangle \cap U_k = \{0\}$?

Please note the keyword effective because using the Gaussian binomial coefficients it is possible to calculate the maximum number of all the subsets possible in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$ but probably not all fulfill the condition that $\langle U_i, U_j \rangle \cap U_k = \{0\}$.

Thanks.

Comment: The spaces $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ so any span of $U_i,U_j,U_k$ will again be a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Also the next sentence: do you mean that we basically replace $n$ by $6$? Would it be possible to explain the situation better?

Comment: Correct! Any span of $\{U_i, U_j, U_k\}$ is $\subseteq  \mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$, with $i, j, k \in \{1, \dots,  n\}$. So The span of $\{U_i, U_j, U_k\}$ generate the subspaces $U_i, \dots, U_n$. And yes $n$ can be replaced by $6$.

Comment: Please answer Christian's questions by editing the question to make sense.  At the moment it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. I edited the question hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: I suggest a clearer wording: ... Furthermore let $ U_1, \dots, U_m$ be a family of $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^n$  
such that $U_i\cap U_j = \{0\}$ and $\langle U_i, U_j \rangle \cap U_k = \{0\}$ for all $i, j, k \in \{1,\dots, m\}$,   $i\neq j \neq k$. What is the  biggest possible $m$?

Comment: I read the question 3 times and still have no idea about what is wanted :-/